# Performance issues UIKit free hand drawing

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit, grand-central-dispatch, uibezierpath

I have converted
[iOS SDK: Advanced Freehand Drawing Techniques](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-advanced-freehand-drawing-techniques--mobile-15602) to Swift but I'm having some performance issues on my iPad Air. It works fine on iPhone 6 (FPS-wise) but the iPad struggles severely! Is it possible to change touchesMoved so that the performance on the iPad is boosted? I've tried to only init UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions... in touchesBegan without luck.

Any ideas are appreciated!

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    incrementalImage = UIImage()
    ctr = 0
    bufIdx = 0
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch{
        pts[0] = touch.locationInView(self)
        isFirstTouchPoint = true
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch{
        if !isBusy {
            var p: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
            self.ctr++
            self.pts[self.ctr] = p
            if self.ctr == 4 {
                self.pts[3] = CGPointMake((self.pts[2].x + self.pts[4].x) / 2.0, (self.pts[2].y + self.pts[4].y) / 2.0)
                for var i = 0; i < 4; i++ {
                    self.pointsBuffer[self.bufIdx+i] = self.pts[i]
                }
                self.bufIdx += 4
                var bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                    var offsetPath = UIBezierPath()
                    if self.bufIdx == 0 {
                        return}

                    var ls = [LineSegment](count: 4, repeatedValue: LineSegment())

                    for var i = 0; i < self.bufIdx; i+=4{
                        if self.isFirstTouchPoint{
                            ls[0] = LineSegment(firstPoint: self.pointsBuffer[0], secondPoint: self.pointsBuffer[0])
                            offsetPath.moveToPoint(ls[0].firstPoint)
                            self.isFirstTouchPoint = false
                        }
                        else{
                            ls[0] = self.lastSegmentOfPrev!
                        }

                        var frac1:CGFloat = self.FF/(self.clamp(self.len_sq(self.pointsBuffer[i], p2: self.pointsBuffer[i+1]),lower: self.LOWER,higher: self.UPPER))

                        var frac2:CGFloat = self.FF/(self.clamp(self.len_sq(self.pointsBuffer[i+1], p2: self.pointsBuffer[i+2]),lower: self.LOWER,higher: self.UPPER))

                        var frac3:CGFloat = self.FF/(self.clamp(self.len_sq(self.pointsBuffer[i+2], p2: self.pointsBuffer[i+3]),lower: self.LOWER,higher: self.UPPER))

                        ls[1] = self.lineSegmentPerpendicularTo(LineSegment(firstPoint: self.pointsBuffer[i],secondPoint: self.pointsBuffer[i+1]), fraction: frac1)
                        ls[2] = self.lineSegmentPerpendicularTo(LineSegment(firstPoint: self.pointsBuffer[i+1],secondPoint: self.pointsBuffer[i+2]), fraction: frac2)
                        ls[3] = self.lineSegmentPerpendicularTo(LineSegment(firstPoint: self.pointsBuffer[i+2],secondPoint: self.pointsBuffer[i+3]), fraction: frac3)

                        offsetPath.moveToPoint(ls[0].firstPoint)
                        offsetPath.addCurveToPoint(ls[3].firstPoint, controlPoint1: ls[1].firstPoint, controlPoint2: ls[2].firstPoint)
                        offsetPath.addLineToPoint(ls[3].secondPoint)
                        offsetPath.addCurveToPoint(ls[0].secondPoint, controlPoint1: ls[2].secondPoint, controlPoint2: ls[1].secondPoint)
                        offsetPath.closePath()
                        self.lastSegmentOfPrev = ls[3]
                    }

                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
                    var rectpath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
                    UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
                    rectpath.fill()
                    if self.incrementalImage != nil{

                        self.incrementalImage!.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
                        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
                        UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
                        offsetPath.stroke()
                        offsetPath.fill()
                        self.incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                        offsetPath.removeAllPoints()

                    }

                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.bufIdx = 0
                        self.setNeedsDisplay()
                    }
                    self.isAwaitingPlay = true
                }

                self.pts[0] = self.pts[3];
                self.pts[1] = self.pts[4];
                self.ctr = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LineSegment
{
    var firstPoint:CGPoint  = CGPointZero
    var secondPoint:CGPoint = CGPointZero
} 

func len_sq(p1:CGPoint,p2:CGPoint)->CGFloat{
    var dx = p2.x - p1.x
    var dy = p2.y - p1.y
    return dx*dx + dy*dy
}

func clamp(value:CGFloat,lower:CGFloat,higher:CGFloat)->CGFloat{
    if value<lower{ return lower}
    if value>higher{return higher}
    return value
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?